# Command to insert code block?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I found the command `SPC m x c` to insert a small code snippet like `~~`. I would like to insert a longer snippet like

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC 
 #+END_SRC
```

Is there a command to do this? I found a way to add it for markdown, which is `SPC m x c`

Comment: See `yasnippts`.

Comment: No you don't need yasnippets. Just ``<s TAB` will insert that begin end src block.

Comment: @EmacsUser `<s TAB` doesn't work for me. Maybe `evil` does interfere here?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

***February 2020 update to this answer:***
From org version 9.2, the old easy templates referred to in this answer is no longer active by default, see this answer for more info: [Why do easy templates, .e.g, "< s TAB" in org 9.2 not work?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46988/why-do-easy-templates-e-g-s-tab-in-org-9-2-not-work) along with the new way to access easy templates which is invoking "org-insert-structure-template" <kbd>C-c C-,</kbd>, or using Spacemacs: <kbd>, i b</kbd>

Original answer:

Yes, it's called **easy templates**.

> Org mode supports insertion of empty structural elements (like
> ‘#+BEGIN_SRC’ and ‘#+END_SRC’ pairs) with just a few key strokes.  This
> is achieved through a native template expansion mechanism.  Note that
> Emacs has several other template mechanisms which could be used in a
> similar way, for example ‘yasnippet’.

> To insert a structural element, type a ‘<’, followed by a template
> selector and ‘TAB’.  Completion takes effect only when the above
> keystrokes are typed on a line by itself.

For your precise question: `<s` then TAB.

*Note it's not specific to spacemacs, since it's from native org-mode*

Comment: ```<s``` doesn't work in Spacemacs? How does one invoke the org-mode template leader key from Spacemacs?

Comment: @shark8me It works in Spacemacs. Just go into the `Insert` mode and then press `<s` followed by `TAB`. That's all.

Comment: Note, this is changing a bit from Org 9.2.  For "`<s`" snippets you need to `(require 'org-tempo)`.  Blocks can also be inserted using the interface accessed via `C-c C-,`.  The syntax of `org-structure-template-alist` is also changed.

Comment: @rasmus `(require 'org-tempo)` did the trick for me, in Spacemacs. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this behavior changed in Org 9.2.  The new method is given in the release notes.  Basically, press `C-c C-,` for a list of templates and then select `s` for source.  @rasmus above explains how to continue using the old way in newer versions of org-mode. https://web.archive.org/web/20190117084828/https://orgmode.org/Changes.html