# Why do easy templates, .e.g, "< s TAB" in org 9.2 not work?

Tags: org-mode, template

[Easy templates](https://orgmode.org/) in Org 9.2 are not working for me on `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30`.

I have changed my `elpa/` directory to `smelpa/`.  I load `emacs -q` and switch to the `*scratch*` buffer and toggle `M-x org-mode`.  A call to  `org-version` returns

```
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ c:/Program Files/emacs-26.1-x86_64/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/org/)
```

When I type `<s` `TAB`, the easy template expands as expected.

```
<s|<-----<press TAB here>

#+BEGIN_SRC 

#+END_SRC
```

Now, to upgrade to Org 9.2, I do `list-packages` and install `org`.  (For some reason `package-install` doesn't return `org`).  Returning to the `*scratch*` buffer, running `org-version` returns

```
Org mode version 9.2 (9.2-elpa @ c:/Users/%USERNAME%/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.2/)
```

It seems like Org 9.2 installed correctly.  The same is true if I just directly install Org 9.2 and create a new `org` buffer (i.e. don't load the default `org` first).  Easy templates won't work in Org 9.2.

I looked around for a bug tracker, but I don't see anything on the [official repo](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

- Did I install Org 9.2 correctly?
- Is there perhaps some compiled file lingering somewhere from a bad install?
- If this is a bug, how do I submit it?  With `report-emacs-bug`?

---

## Update

To address the side questions:

### Did I install Org 9.2 correctly?

Yes.  Installing `org` via `list-packages` will "override" the default version.  This can be seen by running `org-version`.  Note that it may be necessary to restart Emacs (or the Emacs server).

### If this is a bug, how do I submit it? With report-emacs-bug?

According to the [org-mode homepage](https://orgmode.org/) (at the bottom), use `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.  Make sure you [Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) so as not to spam the developers!  This would include checking the [release notes of the new version](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html)!

Comment: Could it be an org-mode dependency that needs an update?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

They changed the template system in orgmode 9.2.

The new mechanism is called *structured template*. The command `org-insert-structure-template` bound to <kbd>C-c C-,</kbd> gives you a list of `#+begin_`-`#+end_` pairs that narrows down while you type and you can use completion.

But, you can also get the old *easy template* system back, either

- by adding `(require 'org-tempo)` to your init file or
- by adding `org-tempo` to the list `org-modules`. You can do that by customizing `org-modules`.

<sup>Note that the answer is mostly a citation of two answers in the [corresponding reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ad68zk/get_easytemplates_back_in_orgmode_92/).</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Others have stated that it's `C-c C-,` now to insert templates.

One cool thing is that you can paste some code, then visual-select it and do `C-c C-, s` and it will wrap your selection inside `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src`.

Before, when it was `<s TAB`, I had made a function to do that but now, I can do it with the native command.  All I have to do is forget about `<s TAB`.

Edit: I installed yasnippet and yasnippet-snippets recently and it adds the completions with <s, <q etc.

```
(use-package yasnippet-snippets
  :ensure t)
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure t
  :config (yas-global-mode 1))
```

I am however glad that I lost those <s completions since it lead me to discover `C-c C-,` which is useful with a visual selection.

Answer (score 4):

As described by Tobias, I had to `(require 'org-tempo)` in `.emacs`.

Additionally, I had to remove any customization to `org-structure-template-alist` or revert it to standard. Then, `C-c C-,` triggers Org-Select menu for structure feature selection and `<s` triggers the usual src block directly.

For org-version 9.3.7, emacs 26.3

Answer (score 2):

You can get completion back by adding `org-tempo` to `org-modules` like so

```el
(add-to-list 'org-modules 'org-tempo t)
```

You will need to restart emacs so when orgmode is loaded it will load `org-tempo` as well.

[Credit to agzam](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12003#issuecomment-465686129)

Answer (score 1):

you can use menu bar `Org => Customize => Browse Org Group` to add

Comment: Add what, to what? Please explain how you think this answers the question. Elaborate.