# Config easy template src code in 0rg 9.2

Tags: org-mode

I read [org mode - Easy Templates in Org 9.2 - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46988/easy-templates-in-org-9-2), which instruct to get back org 9.1

> by adding (require 'org-tempo) to your init file or by adding
>   org-tempo to the list org-modules. You can do that by customizing
>   org-modules.

However, it is nothing of usage,

I can only read the old-fashion style, but cannot change it.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you meant by "I can only read the old-fashion style, but cannot change it", but I wrote an answer explaining how to define templates in the new mechanism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still configure this by changing the variable `org-structure-template-alist` as before, but the format of that variable has been simplified. Before if you wanted `<lem` to expand to

```
#+begin_lemma

#+end_lemma
```

you would add an entry `("lem" "#begin_lemma\n?#end_lemma")` to `org-structure-template-alist`. Now, instead you just add `("lem" "lemma")`.

So for easy cases, the new format is actually much simpler to use, but the older format *was* more general. You can still get more complicated expansions, but you will need to use `tempo-define-template` directly. For example, say you wanted `<js` to expand to:

```
#+begin_export html
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
#end_export
```

You can define a tempo template as follows:

```
(tempo-define-template "inline-js" ; just some name for the template
           '("#+begin_export html" n 
             "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" n p n
             "</script>" n
             "#end_export")
           "<js"
           "Insert a script tag" ; documentation
           'org-tempo-tags)
```

The various `n` in the template add newlines, and the `p` marks where the point will be left after expansion.